# Add an element to a vector inside a struct, from within another struct

Tags: c++

This is most probably trivial and I'm confusing struct allocation and pointers somehow, I apologize for this. I have read answers to similar questions but it didn't help. The code is, as always, way more complicted, this is a reduction from 3000+ lines of code to the gist.

The output I expected was

```
prep 1
main 1
```

Instead, I get

```
prep 1
main 0
```

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Entry
{
    vector<int> list;
};

struct Registry
{
    vector<Entry> entries;

    void prep()
    {
        Entry* entry = new Entry();
        entries.push_back(*entry);
        entry->list.push_back(0);
        cout << "prep " << entry->list.size() << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Registry registry;
    registry.prep();
    cout << "main " << registry.entries[0].list.size() << "\n";

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your program leaks. Why use `new`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't know the number of items beforehand, it's a parser that constructs a tree as it traverses the textual input file. As you've all noticed, I don't know C++ very well. I'd allocate the struct in the function statically, but on exit isn't it remove from the stack? That's why I use `new`: I need it on the heap and survive function exit. Please correct me where I'm wrong :)

Comment: @pid You dereference the dynamically allocated `entry` and copy it into the `vector`, which then controls the lifetime of that new element. You can just as well let the `vector` create the new element and avoid the pointless copy, not to mention in your case leaking the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't store pointers in your `vector<Entry>` so you should not use `new`. Instead add a default constructed `Entry` using `emplace_back`.

A C++17 approach:

```
void prep()
{
    Entry& entry = entries.emplace_back(); // returns a ref the added element
    entry.list.push_back(0);
    cout << "prep " << entry.list.size() << "\n";
}
```

Prior to C++17:

```
void prep()
{
    entries.emplace_back(); // does NOT return a ref the added element
    Entry& entry = entries.back(); // obtain a ref to the added element
    entry.list.push_back(0);
    cout << "prep " << entry.list.size() << "\n";
}
```

If you *do* want to create and maniplate your `Entry` before adding it to `entries`, you can do that too and then `std::move` it into `entries`.

```
void prep()
{
    Entry entry;
    entry.list.push_back(0);
    cout << "prep " << entry.list.size() << "\n";
    entries.push_back(std::move(entry)); // moving is a lot cheaper than copying
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was banging my head for hours :) This has solved several problems in the code with similar patterns. Two more questions please: do I have to cleanup the entries as soon as I'm done processing (to remove the leak)? And on program exit, do the allocations remain and fragment the heap or does C++17 (clang++-12) know the owning process' PID and thus cleanup allocated resources?

Comment: You're welcome! If you use standard containers and no manual memory management (no `new`/`delete` or `new[]`/`delete[]`s), it will be cleaned up automatically. So, in the code in my answer, there will be no leaks. When the program terminates, the objects in these containers will be destroyed properly too, so no need to worry about leaks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the order of the `prep()` function. If you change to push an element into the Element object, and then push it tho the entries vector, the behavior will be the expected.

```
    void prep()
    {
        Entry* entry = new Entry();
        entry->list.push_back(0);
        entries.push_back(*entry);
        cout << "prep " << entry->list.size() << "\n";
    }
```

This is happening, because you uses a copy in the entries list.

It is also possible to store the pointer of the object therefore you can edit the actual instance after you pushed to the entries vector.

Edit:

As Ted mentioned, there is a memory leak, because the entry created with the new operator never deleted. Another approach could be to use smart pointers (however, in this small example it seems overkill, just use reference)

```
    void prep()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Entry> entry = std::make_unique<Entry>();
        entry->list.push_back(0);
        entries.push_back(*entry.get());    // get the pointer behind unique_ptr, then dereference it
        cout << "prep " << entry->list.size() << "\n";
    }    // unique_ptr freed when gets out of scope
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the implementation of `prep()`:

```cpp
void prep()
{
    Entry entry;
    entry.list.push_back(0);
    entries.emplace_back(entry);
    cout << "prep " << entries.back().list.size() << "\n";
}
```

There is no need to allocate a `Entry` on the heap just to make a copy of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I have to accept the other one because @ted was slightly faster and I had already fixed the code when I came back here and read yours. Thanks again and have a nice day!

Comment: No worries, what's important to have your problem fixed.